# Plotting linked polyhedra

Tags: graphics3d, polyhedra

I'd like to plot the TetrahedronFiveCompound as in this image

[image: TetrahedronFiveCompound]

from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tetrahedron5-Compound.html. If possible without the black edges and choosing each tetrahedron's color. I can't find the way to do that in the options for PolyhedronData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extended comment...

The notebook that you can download from the [MathWorld Tetrahedron5-Compound page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tetrahedron5-Compound.html) includes the following code:

```
Off[General::spell1];
Needs["Graphics`Polyhedra`"]
vertices = Vertices[Dodecahedron];
Triangles[{f1_, f2_, f3_, f4_}] := 
    {{f1, f2, f3},
    {f1, f3, f4},
    {f1, f4, f2},
    {f4, f3, f2}}
tetrapoints = {{1, 9, 12, 20}, {2, 10, 13, 16},{3, 6, 14, 17}, {4, 7, 15, 18}, {5, 8, 11, 19}};
poly = (vertices[[#]] &) /@ Flatten[ Triangles /@ tetrapoints, 1];
linearcombination[r_, a_, b_] := (1 - r)*a + (r)*b
HollowTriangle[t_] :=
    
 Block[{a = t[[1]], b = t[[2]], c = t[[3]], aa, bb, cc},
        aa = linearcombination[1/8, a, (b + c)/2];
        bb = linearcombination[1/8, b, (c + a)/2];
        cc = linearcombination[1/8, c, (a + b)/2];
        {{a, b, bb, aa}, {b, c, cc, bb}, {c, a, aa, cc}} ]
On[General::spell1]
tetrapict = Show[Graphics3D[ Polygon /@ Flatten[ HollowTriangle /@ poly,1]],ViewVertical -> {.52, .38, .85}, Boxed -> False]
```

Which would produce:

[image]

Except that more current versions of Mathematica, no longer support the `Vertices[]` function.

Well, ... maybe you could still download an old `Combinatorica` package.

I didn't find an obvious direct equivalent of `Vertices[]` in the new functionality, but someone here can (hopefully) direct you to it.

Maybe someone more familiar with `GraphEmbedding` (see documentation) or the integration of the earlier `Combinatorica` package can help.

All of the above said, this would only get you an image of the

> TetrahedronFiveCompound

You (or others on this site) then need to figure out how to get to the specifics of what you want to achieve, plotting a similar image,

> If possible without the black edges and choosing each tetrahedron's
> color.

I'll give this some more thought as I can.

Comment: I didn't realize I could download the code from Mathworld! I thought it was some kind of default drawing mode, but it seems it is more manual than that. I'll see if I can tweak the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
data=PolyhedronData["TetrahedronFiveCompound", "Polyhedra"];
Graphics3D[
 Riffle[ColorData[97] /@ Range[5], 
  data]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I meant without faces, but this is nice too.